# Kurento Media Server MCU

Tags: kurento

I am building an app using WebRtc in combination with Kurento Media Server.
As far as I understand, Kurento's default approach dealing with multi-point is Routing.

**How can one change Routing to MCU?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to combine all incoming streams into one single stream, so that each participant receives only one stream, you can use a special type of mixing media element called `Composite`.

There are some things that you should consider, however:

- The task of mixing those streams is quite CPU intense. Monitor the load of your system to know how it behaves.
- The size of each stream, once combined, depends on the total number of streams. A mesh layout is forced into an 800x600 stream.

Comment: @andrey Please see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565647/mixing-streams-concept-in-kurento-media-server) SO answer.